# Shortcode is not working in my wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

After I installed the demo content in wordpress. I'm not able to see the content. Instead of that, the shotcode is shown.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because you haven't install or activated the plugins came with theme. If your theme use some kind of visual builder to create pages. Please install and activate that plugin.